# qtcreator fuerte and ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ros, ubuntu, ros-fuerte, ubuntu-precise, qtcreator

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello,

I am trying to use qtcreator with fuerte and ubuntu 12.04.

When make rosmake on shell it is all fine!

When i run qtcreator in the shell or out and i try to open the cmakelist.txt.
I get from erro form qtcreator:
[rosbuild] Error from syntax check of hyselam_topo/manifest.xml

CMake Error at /opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/rosbuild/private.cmake:78 (message):
[rosbuild] Syntax check of hyselam_topo/manifest.xml failed; aborting
Call Stack (most recent call first):
/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:174 (_rosbuild_check_manifest)
CMakeLists.txt:18 (rosbuild_init)

What could be?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33067/qtcreator-fuerte-and-ubuntu-12.04/) by [Filipe Santos](https://answers.ros.org/users/907/filipe-santos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 346 on 2012-05-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have a look at [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/11661/setting-up-qt-creator-for-ros/?answer=17589#post-id-17589) link .. I faced the same issue as yours ... and now it is resolved.

---

Originally posted by [CBK](https://answers.ros.org/users/3317/cbk/) with karma: 28 on 2012-10-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1